# Any free Java library to perform Cox's proportional hazards regression

Tags: java, statistics, cox-regression

Does anybody know of any library that has Cox's proportional hazard regression apart from JavaStat that is rather slow...Please let me know.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

[BDVal](http://campagnelab.org/software/bdval/) is an open source (GPL) Java project with a [Cox Regression mode](http://campagnelab.org/software/bdval/reference-documentation/bdval-modes/cox-regression/).